# Why the OnBeforeUnload doesn't intercept the back button in my GWT app?

Tags: gwt, onbeforeunload

I have a hook on the beforeUnload event. If i try to click on a link, reload or close the tab or the navigator, the app ask for confirmation before leaving. That's the desired behavior.

But if click on the back button or the backspace outside an input, no confirmation.

At the beginning of the html :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
 if (confirmEnabled)
    return "";
}
```

And i use the Gwt PlaceHistoryMapper.

What did i miss ? Where did i forgot to look ?

Thanks !

Comment: And the _back button_ takes you where? within or outside your app?

Comment: Within. It acts normally, just without the confirmation popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you stay within your app, because it's a *single-page app*, it doesn't by definition *unload*, so there's no `beforeunload` event.

When using *Places*, the equivalent is the `PlaceChangeRequestEvent` dispatched by the `PlaceController` on the `EventBus`. This event is **also** dispatched in `beforeunload` BTW, and is the basis for the `mayStop()` handling in *Activities*.

Outside GWT, in the JS world, an equivalent would be `hashchange` and/or `popstate`, depending on your `PlaceHistoryHandler.Historian` implementation (the default one uses `History.newItem()`, so that would be `hashchange`).

Comment: For the anchors in my app, i added a JS bit to intercept the click. That's what i missed. Now i want to handle the PlaceChangeRequestEvent but i don't know how to stop or continue once i asked for confirmation

Comment: By "ask for confirmation", do you mean `setMessage()` on the `PlaceChangeRequestEvent` or rolling your own in the event handler? Use the former, confirmation and stop/continue comes for free.