# How to trigger onbeforeunload with back button in an ajax based application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I have an ajax based application (ie no page 'reloads` when getting new data).

Initially I wanted to find a way to prevent navigation when unsaved data was present on a form.

I came across `window.onbeforeunload`.

That didn't work when clicking `a` links (where content is loaded via ajax and pop/push state changes the url).

I added some handling of the `a` links but need to use the default `window.onbeforeunload` to cover the standard means of leaving a page (ie manually entering a new URL or using the back/forwards buttons).

The code below works for:

- `a` links
- page refresh
- manually entering a new url

But is not triggering `window.onbeforeunload` when using the back button (in Chrome and Firefox).

Is there something awry with the implementation below or is `window.onbeforeunload` not meant to be triggered when using the back button?

```
var save_state = true;

// on entering data into an input field, the save button fades in 
// and the save_state changes
$(document).on('keypress', '.class1 input', function() {
if (save_state) {
$(".save_button").fadeIn();
save_state = false;
};
// bind the click event to 'a' (overiding normal link behaviour)
$( "a" ).bind( "click", function(e) {
if (save_state == false) {
e.preventDefault();
alert("Save before leaving.");
// stop the other 'a' bound handlers from being triggered
e.stopPropagation();
return;
}
});
// also cover standard actions when user tries to leave page
// (back/forward or entering a new url manually etc)
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
return 'Save before leaving.';
};
}); 

// when clicking save, fade out the button and revert the save_state
$(document).on('click', '.save_button button', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).parent().fadeOut();
save_state = true;
// 'unbind' onbeforeunload
window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```

**Edit:**

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13359341/1063287), I think it is based on the ajax nature of the app:

> As long as you stay within your app, because it's a single-page app,
>   it doesn't by definition unload, so there's no beforeunload event.

So I think I may need to look at other ways to trigger the event on back/forwards buttons.

Comment: are you looking for disabled the back button or you want on the same page when user press the back button?

Comment: setInterval a function that detects location.href changes?

Comment: window.onpopstate? It's [new](http://caniuse.com/#search=pop), tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked in to triggering `window.unload` on `popstate` but didn't have any luck with that.

I ended up changing the logic so that as soon as changes were made, they were saved in the database.

I was using [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) for the form input handling and just added some extra calls to it.

In `selectize.js` ([here](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/dist/js/selectize.js#L1012)):

```
if ($target.hasClass('create')) {
    self.createItem();
} else {
    value = $target.attr('data-value');
```

became:

```
if ($target.hasClass('create')) {
    self.createItem();
    $(".saved_message_div").fadeIn(400).delay(2000).fadeOut(400); // new
    updateDatabaseFunction(); //  new
} else {
    value = $target.attr('data-value');
    $(".saved_message_div").fadeIn(400).delay(2000).fadeOut(400); // new
    updateDatabaseFunction(); // new
```

AND ([here](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/dist/js/selectize.js#L2050)):

```
while (values.length) {
    self.removeItem(values.pop());
}

self.showInput();
```

became:

```
while (values.length) {
    self.removeItem(values.pop());
}

$(".saved_message_div").fadeIn(400).delay(2000).fadeOut(400); // new
updateDatabaseFunction(); // new
self.showInput();
```

And in my own script, the prompt for deleting `selectize.js` items stayed the same:

```
onDelete: function(values) {
confirm(values.length > 1 ? 'Are you sure you want to remove these ' + values.length + ' items?' : 'Are you sure you want to remove "' + values[0] + '"?');
```