# How to intercept back button in Sammy.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application, sammy.js

I´m currently using Sammy.js in my Single Page Application and want to notify the user if he tries to leave a site with changed content.

Is it somehow possible to intercept the back command or any other routing change to display some hint before?

Comment: Something like window.onbeforeunload ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly onbeforeunload isn´t called in single page applications. look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358476/why-the-onbeforeunload-doesnt-intercept-the-back-button-in-my-gwt-app . this means, that I need to interfer with Sammy.js

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23955762/394418) for one way to do what you're looking for. The group I work for actively uses this technique to show a dialog whenever a user tries to navigate away from a page that has been modified but not saved.

Outside of the solution I point out there, you cannot prevent the back button from actually navigating them. If you could do that with JavaScript, that could be easily abused to keep users on a page until they closed the browser.